# Find the number of possible 4x4 matrices such that :

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Find the number of possible 4x4 matrices such that :

1) each row has two 0's and two 1's
2) each column has two 0's and two 1's

example :
$$\large \begin{pmatrix} 1&1&0&0\\1&1&0&0\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

---

I am getting $90$ by counting all the cases manually and it took 2 hours. Is there any neat way to solve this problem ? Further, I know that the first row can be arranged in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just look for the matrices with $1,1,0,0$ in the top row, then each of those matrices has five others, that you get by shuffling the columns.
Since the first column starts with a 1, there are three positions for the other 1 in that column.  So if you only look for matrices with $1,1,0,0$ in the top row and $1,1,0,0$ in the first column, each of those is one of 18 matrices that you get by shuffling the four columns and shuffling the bottom three rows.
Now you only have to show there are five ways to complete the square.